# colortbl rowcolor overtop of @{decl}

Tags: tables, beamer, colortbl

I have tables with many `$\pm$` values that I was using the `@{decl}` command to have nice alignment.  However, I wanted to add some row colors.  Trying to use colortbl I found that the cell/row color was on top of my `$\pm$`.  I tried playing with the overhang, but then the color wasn't behind the `$\pm$`.

MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{$\pm$}r}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{value} \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\ 
\rowcolor{white}[0pt] 2&3 \\
\rowcolor{yellow}[0pt] 3&4\\
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{l@{$\pm$}r}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{value} \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\ 
\rowcolor{white} 2&3 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 3&4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there any nice/simple way to do this LaTeX?  I'm sure there is something complicated, but I thought this would be a relatively simple use case.  If it possibly matters, I'm making a Poster in Beamer.

[image: Latex Table Results]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`dcolumn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package to easily get the alignment (with the right spacing around `\pm`) and the color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{D{,}{{}\pm{}}{1,1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{L}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{value} \\
\hline
1,2 \\ 
\rowcolor{blue!30} 2,3 \\
\rowcolor{yellow!60} 3,4 \\
\end{tabular}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{L}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{value} \\
\hline
1,2 \\ 
\rowcolor{blue!30}[0pt] 2,3 \\
\rowcolor{yellow!60}[0pt] 3,4 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I thought to mention in my answer that the spacing around pm is distinctly odd if done that way. That certainly looks a lot better.  Depends a bit what the real example is rather than this (nicely small) MWE:-)

Comment: This works!  I hadn't used dcolumn before and wouldn't have thought of cross-purposing it this way. The alignment works ok - I have very few cells that end up looking strange this way (can fix by hand).

Answer (score 5):

The coloured pannels are laid out before each cell content so you want to make the cell before the `@{}` be extended *under* it and the one after the `@{}` to not extend back over it.

[image]

Unfortunately I think that means something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{$\pm$}r}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{value} \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\ 
\rowcolor{white}[0pt] 2&3 \\
%\rowcolor{yellow}[0pt]
\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{yellow}[0pt][20pt]}l@{$\pm$}}{3}&
\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{yellow}[0pt]}l}{4}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is somewhat easier than I was expecting, but it will get quite ugly when I have many (right now, 3 or 4) of these value with error sets.

Comment: sorry. blame the author of the package.

Comment: Luckily the author of colortbl gets plenty of credit for the dcolumn package and the excellent Companion book. (-:

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,color}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l@{$\pm$}l}[colortbl-like]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\clap{value}} \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\ 
\rowcolor{white} 2 & 3 \\
\rowcolor{yellow} 3 & 4\\
5 & 6 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]